# AttributeError on End-to-End ML Project - 'DataTransformation' object has no attribute 'data_transformation_config'

Tags: python, pandas

I am following the process shown on [Wine Quality Prediction End-to-End ML Project](https://youtu.be/pxk1Fr33-L4?si=zqJ_Ice6YT8pLYzJ) on Krish Naik's YouTube channel to do a Flight Fare Prediction Project.

I run this cell of data transformation pipeline on [03_data_transformation.ipynb](https://github.com/MdEhsanulHaqueKanan/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/blob/main/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb):

```
try:
    config = ConfigurationManager()
    data_transformation_config = config.get_data_transformation_config()
    data_transformation = DataTransformation(config=data_transformation_config)
    # data_transformation.train_test_spliting()
    # New Line
    data_transformation.initiate_data_transformation()
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataTransformation' object has no attribute 'data_transformation_config'
```

Here is the traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
g:\Machine_Learning_Projects\iNeuron internship\Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project\research\03_data_transformation.ipynb Cell 10 line 9
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=6'>7</a>     data_transformation.initiate_data_transformation()
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=7'>8</a> except Exception as e:
----> <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=8'>9</a>     raise e

g:\Machine_Learning_Projects\iNeuron internship\Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project\research\03_data_transformation.ipynb Cell 10 line 7
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=3'>4</a>     data_transformation = DataTransformation(config=data_transformation_config)
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=4'>5</a>     # data_transformation.train_test_spliting()
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=5'>6</a>     # New Line
----> <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=6'>7</a>     data_transformation.initiate_data_transformation()
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=7'>8</a> except Exception as e:
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=8'>9</a>     raise e

g:\Machine_Learning_Projects\iNeuron internship\Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project\research\03_data_transformation.ipynb Cell 10 line 8
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=77'>78</a> logger.info(f' transformed df data head: \n{df.head().to_string()}')
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=79'>80</a> # df.to_csv(self.data_transformation_config.transformed_data_file_path, index = False, header= True)
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=80'>81</a> # New Line
---> <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=81'>82</a> df.to_excel(self.data_transformation_config.transformed_data_file_path, index = False, header= True)
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=82'>83</a> logger.info("transformed data is stored")
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=83'>84</a> df.head(1)

AttributeError: 'DataTransformation' object has no attribute 'data_transformation_config'
```

Here is the code of data transformation cell, which contains `data_transformation_config`:

```
class DataTransformation:

    # New Function Added
    # https://github.com/yash1314/Flight-Price-Prediction/blob/main/src/utils.py
    def convert_to_minutes(self, duration):
        try:
            hours, minute = 0, 0
            for i in duration.split():
                if 'h' in i:
                    hours = int(i[:-1])
                elif 'm' in i:
                    minute = int(i[:-1])
            return hours * 60 + minute
        except :
            return None 

    def __init__(self, config: DataTransformationConfig):
        self.config = config

    
    ## Note: You can add different data transformation techniques such as Scaler, PCA and all
    #You can perform all kinds of EDA in ML cycle here before passing this data to the model

    # I am only adding train_test_spliting cz this data is already cleaned up

    # New Code Added Start
    def initiate_data_transformation(self):
        ## reading the data
        # df = pd.read_csv(self.config.data_path)
        # New Line
        df = pd.read_excel(self.config.data_path)

        logger.info('Read data completed')
        logger.info(f'df dataframe head: \n{df.head().to_string()}')

        ## dropping null values
        df.dropna(inplace = True)

        ## Date of journey column transformation
        df['journey_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_of_Journey'], format ="%d/%m/%Y").dt.day
        df['journey_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_of_Journey'], format ="%d/%m/%Y").dt.month

        ## encoding total stops.
        df.replace({'Total_Stops': {'non-stop' : 0, '1 stop': 1, '2 stops': 2, '3 stops': 3, '4 stops': 4}}, inplace = True)

        ## ecoding airline, source, and destination
        df_airline = pd.get_dummies(df['Airline'], dtype=int)
        df_source = pd.get_dummies(df['Source'],  dtype=int)
        df_dest = pd.get_dummies(df['Destination'], dtype=int)

        ## dropping first columns of each categorical variables.
        df_airline.drop('Trujet', axis = 1, inplace = True)
        df_source.drop('Banglore', axis = 1, inplace = True)
        df_dest.drop('Banglore', axis = 1, inplace = True)

        df = pd.concat([df, df_airline, df_source, df_dest], axis = 1)
       
        ## handling duration column
        # df['duration'] = df['Duration'].apply(convert_to_minutes)
        # New Line Added
        df['duration'] = df['Duration'].apply(self.convert_to_minutes)
        upper_time_limit = df.duration.mean() + 1.5 * df.duration.std()
        df['duration'] = df['duration'].clip(upper = upper_time_limit)

        ## encodign duration column
        bins = [0, 120, 360, 1440]  # custom bin intervals for 'Short,' 'Medium,' and 'Long'
        labels = ['Short', 'Medium', 'Long'] # creating labels for encoding

        df['duration'] = pd.cut(df['duration'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
        df.replace({'duration': {'Short':1, 'Medium':2, 'Long': 3}}, inplace = True)
        
        ## dropping the columns
        cols_to_drop = cols_to_drop = ['Airline', 'Date_of_Journey', 'Source', 'Destination', 'Route', 'Dep_Time', 'Arrival_Time', 'Duration', 'Additional_Info', 'Delhi', 'Kolkata']

        df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis = 1, inplace = True)

        logger.info('df data transformation completed')
        logger.info(f' transformed df data head: \n{df.head().to_string()}')

        # df.to_csv(self.data_transformation_config.transformed_data_file_path, index = False, header= True)
        # New Line
        df.to_excel(self.data_transformation_config.transformed_data_file_path, index = False, header= True)
        logger.info("transformed data is stored")
        df.head(1)
        ## splitting the data into training and target data
        X = df.drop('Price', axis = 1)
        y = df['Price']
        
        ## accessing the feature importance.
        select = ExtraTreesRegressor()
        select.fit(X, y)

        # plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
        # fig_importances = pd.Series(select.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
        # fig_importances.nlargest(20).plot(kind='barh')
    
        # ## specify the path to the "visuals" folder using os.path.join
        # visuals_folder = 'visuals'
        # if not os.path.exists(visuals_folder):
        #     os.makedirs(visuals_folder)

        # ## save the plot in the visuals folder
        # plt.savefig(os.path.join(visuals_folder, 'feature_importance_plot.png'))
        # logger.info('feature imp figure saving is successful')

        ## further Splitting the data.
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42, shuffle = True) 
        logger.info('final splitting the data is successful')
        

        ## returning splitted data and data_path.
        return (
            X_train, 
            X_test, 
            y_train, 
            y_test,
            self.data_transformation_config.transformed_data_file_path
        )class DataTransformation:

    # New Function Added
    # https://github.com/yash1314/Flight-Price-Prediction/blob/main/src/utils.py
    def convert_to_minutes(self, duration):
        try:
            hours, minute = 0, 0
            for i in duration.split():
                if 'h' in i:
                    hours = int(i[:-1])
                elif 'm' in i:
                    minute = int(i[:-1])
            return hours * 60 + minute
        except :
            return None 

    def __init__(self, config: DataTransformationConfig):
        self.config = config

    
    ## Note: You can add different data transformation techniques such as Scaler, PCA and all
    #You can perform all kinds of EDA in ML cycle here before passing this data to the model

    # I am only adding train_test_spliting cz this data is already cleaned up

    # New Code Added Start
    def initiate_data_transformation(self):
        ## reading the data
        # df = pd.read_csv(self.config.data_path)
        # New Line
        df = pd.read_excel(self.config.data_path)

        logger.info('Read data completed')
        logger.info(f'df dataframe head: \n{df.head().to_string()}')

        ## dropping null values
        df.dropna(inplace = True)

        ## Date of journey column transformation
        df['journey_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_of_Journey'], format ="%d/%m/%Y").dt.day
        df['journey_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_of_Journey'], format ="%d/%m/%Y").dt.month

        ## encoding total stops.
        df.replace({'Total_Stops': {'non-stop' : 0, '1 stop': 1, '2 stops': 2, '3 stops': 3, '4 stops': 4}}, inplace = True)

        ## ecoding airline, source, and destination
        df_airline = pd.get_dummies(df['Airline'], dtype=int)
        df_source = pd.get_dummies(df['Source'],  dtype=int)
        df_dest = pd.get_dummies(df['Destination'], dtype=int)

        ## dropping first columns of each categorical variables.
        df_airline.drop('Trujet', axis = 1, inplace = True)
        df_source.drop('Banglore', axis = 1, inplace = True)
        df_dest.drop('Banglore', axis = 1, inplace = True)

        df = pd.concat([df, df_airline, df_source, df_dest], axis = 1)
       
        ## handling duration column
        # df['duration'] = df['Duration'].apply(convert_to_minutes)
        # New Line Added
        df['duration'] = df['Duration'].apply(self.convert_to_minutes)
        upper_time_limit = df.duration.mean() + 1.5 * df.duration.std()
        df['duration'] = df['duration'].clip(upper = upper_time_limit)

        ## encodign duration column
        bins = [0, 120, 360, 1440]  # custom bin intervals for 'Short,' 'Medium,' and 'Long'
        labels = ['Short', 'Medium', 'Long'] # creating labels for encoding

        df['duration'] = pd.cut(df['duration'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
        df.replace({'duration': {'Short':1, 'Medium':2, 'Long': 3}}, inplace = True)
        
        ## dropping the columns
        cols_to_drop = cols_to_drop = ['Airline', 'Date_of_Journey', 'Source', 'Destination', 'Route', 'Dep_Time', 'Arrival_Time', 'Duration', 'Additional_Info', 'Delhi', 'Kolkata']

        df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis = 1, inplace = True)

        logger.info('df data transformation completed')
        logger.info(f' transformed df data head: \n{df.head().to_string()}')

        # df.to_csv(self.data_transformation_config.transformed_data_file_path, index = False, header= True)
        # New Line
        df.to_excel(self.data_transformation_config.transformed_data_file_path, index = False, header= True)
        logger.info("transformed data is stored")
        df.head(1)
        ## splitting the data into training and target data
        X = df.drop('Price', axis = 1)
        y = df['Price']
        
        ## accessing the feature importance.
        select = ExtraTreesRegressor()
        select.fit(X, y)

        # plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
        # fig_importances = pd.Series(select.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
        # fig_importances.nlargest(20).plot(kind='barh')
    
        # ## specify the path to the "visuals" folder using os.path.join
        # visuals_folder = 'visuals'
        # if not os.path.exists(visuals_folder):
        #     os.makedirs(visuals_folder)

        # ## save the plot in the visuals folder
        # plt.savefig(os.path.join(visuals_folder, 'feature_importance_plot.png'))
        # logger.info('feature imp figure saving is successful')

        ## further Splitting the data.
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42, shuffle = True) 
        logger.info('final splitting the data is successful')
        

        ## returning splitted data and data_path.
        return (
            X_train, 
            X_test, 
            y_train, 
            y_test,
            self.data_transformation_config.transformed_data_file_path
        )
```

Here is the code of configuration manager, which contains `get_data_transformation_config()` function.

```
class ConfigurationManager:
    def __init__(
        self,
        config_filepath = CONFIG_FILE_PATH,
        params_filepath = PARAMS_FILE_PATH,
        schema_filepath = SCHEMA_FILE_PATH):

        self.config = read_yaml(config_filepath)
        self.params = read_yaml(params_filepath)
        self.schema = read_yaml(schema_filepath)

        create_directories([self.config.artifacts_root])


    
    def get_data_transformation_config(self) -> DataTransformationConfig:
        config = self.config.data_transformation

        create_directories([config.root_dir])

        data_transformation_config = DataTransformationConfig(
            root_dir=config.root_dir,
            data_path=config.data_path,
        )

        return data_transformation_config
```

Here is [my file in GitHub](https://github.com/MdEhsanulHaqueKanan/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/blob/main/research/03_data_transformation.ipynb).

My file encoding is UTF-8.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You have ```df.to_excel(self.data_transformation_config.transformed_data_file_path, index ...```, but shouldn't that be ```self.config.transformed_data_file_path```?

Comment: In `DataTransformation` you have `def __init__(self, config: DataTransformationConfig): self.config = config` - so you have it as `self.config`

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: @ewokx Thanks! Your solution works! Please, add your answer and I will be more than happy to choose it as the right answer.

Comment: @ewokx I am facing a new issue. Would you please help me to fix it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77546158/data-transformation-issue-on-end-to-end-ml-project-keyerror-date-of-journey?noredirect=1#comment136710511_77546158

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was using the wrong variable.

Instead of

```
df.to_excel(self.data_transformation_config.transformed_data_file_path, index = False, header= True)
```

It really should be:

```
df.to_excel(self.config.transformed_data_file_path, index = False, header= True)
```

and change the reference to this line:

```
return (
            X_train, 
            X_test, 
            y_train, 
            y_test,
            self.data_transformation_config.transformed_data_file_path
        )
```

to

```
return (
            X_train, 
            X_test, 
            y_train, 
            y_test,
            self.config.transformed_data_file_path
        )
```